# Firebase DatabaseException

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I get this error when I open a particular activity

> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.joe.metery.ChatMessage

The error can be found in this method:

```
 private void displayChatMessage() {

    ListView listOfMessages = findViewById(R.id.list_of_messages);
    adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<ChatMessage>(this, ChatMessage.class, R.layout.list_item_message,
            mDatabaseRefUser.child("Chat").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())
                    .child(userID).child(uploadID).child("Messages")) {
        @Override
        protected void populateView(View v, ChatMessage model, int position) {

            TextView messageText, messageUser, messageTime;

            messageText = v.findViewById(R.id.message_text);
            messageUser = v.findViewById(R.id.message_user);
            messageTime = v.findViewById(R.id.message_time);
            model.setMessageTime(new Date().getTime());

            messageText.setText(model.getMessageText());
            messageUser.setText(model.getMessageUser());
            messageTime.setText(DateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy (HH:mm:ss)", model.getMessageTime()));

        }
    };

    listOfMessages.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

I couldn't find it myself after doing a lot of changes.

Comment: I have commented out everything within `populateView` but I still get error.

Comment: Okay now I know the issue, but I don't know why it gives me problem. When I uncomment `listOfMessages.setAdapter(adapter);` it works. But why?

Comment: The data that exists at `mDatabaseRefUser.child("Chat").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child(userID).child(uploadID).child("Messages")` is not a `ChatMessage`, but a `String`. If that doesn't explain, please edit your question to include the JSON at this exact location (as text, no screenshots please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Please add your database structure.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
 Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("chats"); 
FirebaseListOptions<ChatMessage> options = new FirebaseListOptions.Builder<ChatMessage>()
                .setQuery(query, ChatMessage.class)
                 .setLayout(R.layout.message)
                .build();
```

adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter(options){

Comment: When answering an old question, your answer would be much more useful to other StackOverflow users if you included some context to explain how your answer helps. See: [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).